# Blazor server side oninput event causing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side

I am building a sample component with a form that takes a credit card number. I am attempting to add an oninput event to the InputText component, which fails to function properly once attached.  Without the event the form functions normally. It does not matter what the supplied method to the event does, it always fails to function properly.

code:

```
<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm Model="@card" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="ccNumberId">Debit or Credit Card Number</label><br />
                <InputText id="ccNumberId" @bind-Value="card.Number" 
                     @oninput="@(e => FormatCreditCardNumber())"       /><br />
                @numberFormat
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="ccYearId">Expiration Year</label><br />
                <InputText id="ccYearId" @bind-Value="card.ExpYear" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="ccMonthId">Expiration Month</label><br />
                <InputText id="ccMonthId" @bind-Value="card.ExpMonth" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="ccCvcId">CVC</label><br />
                <InputText id="ccCvcId" @bind-Value="card.Cvc" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm>

@code {
    string numberFormat;

    private StripeChargeModel card = new StripeChargeModel();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showOnToast", "#paymentToast");
    }

    private void FormatCreditCardNumber()
    {
        if (card.Number.Length == 4)
        {
            numberFormat = String.Empty;
            numberFormat = card.Number + "-";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you're binding value by `@bind-Value="card.Number"` instead of by [`@bind-value:oninput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#data-binding). The `@bind-Value` directive binds value when value changes (i.e. the `onchange` event). And the **`oninput`** event fires **before** **`onchange`**: when the first keystroke event fires, the `card.Number` is `null` because the `@onchange` event has not arrived yet.

In order to fix that issue, you need prevent `card.Number` is `null` when checking `card.Number.Length == 4` otherwise it will throw a `System.NullReferenceException` when the first keystroke 
event fires:

```
private void FormatCreditCardNumber()
{
    if (card.Number.Length == 4)
    if (card.Number?.Length == 4)
    {
        numberFormat = String.Empty;
        numberFormat = card.Number + "-";
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I implement the same operation using @bind-value:oninput?

Comment: @user1206480 Sorry for the confusing words "instead of..". I'm not suggesting you should use `@bind-value:event='input'` but showing you the official docs link where it describes that the `oninput` event is triggered when key stroking and `bind-Value` actually binds value when value changes.